# Template comment for link-only answers is not good

Tags: discussion

Can we please stop using this canned comment for link-only answers?

> A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers)

Found [here](https://sobotics.org/auto-comments/) and used by many reviewers.

The issue is that this comment is too ambiguous and could even give the wrong message.

I mean...

> A link to a solution is welcome

Nope. It's not. And it's really irritating to read this under a link-only answer.

I find this first sentence absolutely counter-productive because of its ambiguity. The answer should be posted here, not elsewhere. A link should only support the answer posted here.

This comment does not explain this properly, unfortunately.

The first sentence is really misleading, and the rest somehow encourages to copypaste content found elsewhere into answers here.

Can we please stop using this specific comment, or maybe better: refactor it so that it doesn't say "yeah a link is cool" in the first sentence?

Comment: What about something simular to the review comment: _"While this link may answer the question, bla bla bla"_

Comment: @AndréKool Sure, why not, it's an option. Anything less ambiguous than the current one would be ok for me. I don't have a magic solution unfortunately, so I'm asking the community.

Comment: If you don't like the current comment, could you suggest a better/other version? I think most reviewers wouldn't have a problem in changing it.

Comment: @Filnor I would go with something much simpler. Like "Please avoid posting just a link. Your answer should be complete without it - if the link breaks or changes, your answer has no value (link-only answers are eventually deleted). Thank you."  Or anything in the same spirit...

Comment: Perhaps the problem lies in "to a solution", as we do want solutions to be posted here, as answers. Would "A link to useful information is welcome, but [...]" be an improvement?

Comment: @duplode The gist of my post here is that "A link is welcome but" is the issue. A link is not "welcome". We don't want links, we want answers. That's really the core of my problem with this comment.

Comment: @Moritz A link can be welcome in quite a few situations -- for instance, as pointers to a source backing up something said in an answer, or as suggestions for relevant further reading, in cases including the extra information would make the answer too long or broaden its scope too much. (That said, I do think a leaner comment with the desired behaviour upfront, in the vein of what you are suggesting, could be an improvement.)

Comment: @duplode `as pointers to a source backing up something said in an answer` Yes, absolutely. A link is great to *support the answer*. But it should not be the answer. Or even most of it. And my issue is that this comment does not explain that properly and is even probably a bit counter productive (and at least very confusing for many people).

Comment: Just so you all know, that [template comment was written by Shog9](https://gist.github.com/Shog9/df07b6dc95a66ced489c495c15da7dd1). Also, it looks like you've conveniently chosen to ignore the "but please ensure your answer is useful without it" part after the first part of that sentence. When read together, it makes total sense.

Comment: Sure if you read the comment in a certain way it makes sense. It shouldn't stop us from making a better version if it's possible. And I think it is possible, and needed. The current version is not good enough. "A link is welcome but" is really a problem for me. A link is not welcome.

Comment: But maybe this is exactly where we disagree: about the fact that posting a link is ok as long as we add some content copied from the source. Such answers are not good answers in my opinion. I don't come to SO to find links that I could find elsewhere. I come here because humans write real answers. It's ok to add a link to *your* answer - it's not ok to answer with just a link and then copy content just to fill it and pretend we have not just a link but a real answer.

Answer (score 27):

A link to a solution *is* welcome. It's just not welcome *on its own*. However, it can definitely be rephrased (and shortened) to avoid confusing people who might not read the whole comment like this situation. Something like:

> Please [add context to your link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, and then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. **[Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://$siteurl$/help/deleted-answers)**.

Comment: This looks great to me. Making that last part bold gets the point across very well. No telling how it would look to a new user, though. Wonder if we could have all the new users vote on their preferred way to be told they did something wrong...

Comment: I still have an issue with "quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to" as I explained in my comments under the question, but this is really a good suggestion. Nicely done.

Comment: Although, unless someone posts another alternative, I think I'll go with "Please avoid posting just a link. Your answer should be complete without it - if the link breaks or changes, your answer has no value (link-only answers are eventually deleted). Thank you." now. It reflects rather accurately how I see things.

Comment: @Moritz You're free to use whatever blurb you wanna use (so long as it is not rude, etc.), but stuff people write elsewhere is also "real stuff written by humans". Why reinvent the wheel when we can use our human intellect to quote the most relevant part of some helpful off-site link? There are many situations where that quoted blurb is directly helpful, but the rest of the content could or would be helpful to varying degrees, too. Should we just say "I know of a great link you can learn from but I won't post it here" instead? That seems like a pretty harmful alternative.

Comment: @TylerH In theory I agree but this is, what, 1% of the links posted? The other 99% are "try github/thing it works for me" and these are the ones where the comment I don't like is posted on. :)

Comment: @Moritz If that is the content of the answer then it is delete-worthy, but the same standards should apply regardless of the link. If you are linking to something where 100% of the code or content would be necessary to answer the question, quote the whole thing or leave a comment instead.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative, more concise:

> Link-only answers are discouraged. Please include all the necessary information in your answer, and quote from the linked page in case it becomes unavailable.