# Is the Low Quality Answers Queue review comment for link-only answers providing appropriate guidance?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts

### Background

The current review comment for "This is a link-only answer (and not spam)" reads:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

The advice here, specifically, "it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference" seems to be giving the incorrect impression. Users who engage with these comments and try to fix their post appear to be just copying from the site they've linked.

However, this creates a follow-up issue of plagiarism/duplicated information. Either the question should have been closed as a duplicate (when they found their answer on an existing Stack Overflow Q & A thread) or it needs to have been [cited properly](/help/referencing).

Here are some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72999098/revisions ([Screenshot of timeline 72999098](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KMn1.png))
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72998301/revisions ([Screenshot of timeline 72998301](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blXU3.png))
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72938824/revisions ([Screenshot of timeline 72938824](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYSGG.png))

Notes:

1. I've intentionally chosen deleted answers here so as to reduce the meta effect on any existing answers to which this might also apply.
2. I don't know statistically how common this is as tracking down posts which meet these criteria is difficult for normal users.

---

### Issue and Proposal

I find the existing review comment has two main issues:

1. It does not accurately inform the user of the site's attribution requirements
2. Questions on Stack Overflow are generally very specific. It is unlikely that an off-site resource answers the *exact* question posed on Stack Overflow.

I propose something more along the lines of:

> Answers on Stack Overflow must be [self-contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Link-only answers rarely answer the specific question asked and can become useless if the linked page changes. Please [edit] your answer so that it contains a clear solution to this specific question. Don't forget to provide [appropriate attribution](/help/referencing) when using content written by others.

The hope being that something like the above would give more actionable advice to the users who want to improve their answer.

---

### Related proposals here on MSO:

- [Template comment for link-only answers is not good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368513/15497888) (for a different link-only comment and focuses on links themselves and not the follow-up issue of users actually taking the comment's advice)
- [LQP - Delete reason for link-only to Stack Overflow answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358817/15497888) (which suggests more tailored advice when the link is to another Stack Overflow Q & A)
- [Should we have a separate delete recommendation for duplicate-suggestion link-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415008/15497888) (also suggests a separate comment for when the link-only answer links to other Stack Overflow Q & A)

Comment: Probably worth addressing this paragraph from [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): "*Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.*" - I've seen people respond to the original link-only comment by just copying and pasting entire pages verbatim without any/much accompanying text, which then introduces another problem to be dealt with.

Comment: I think case #2, where it was originally a link to another Stack Overflow answer, should be handled differently. If they are just going to edit to copy the other answer as their entire solution, they should instead flag the question as a duplicate. Related MSO post: [Should we have a separate delete recommendation for duplicate-suggestion link-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415008/2745495)

Comment: @GinoMempin: It's not guaranteed that the question is a duplicate.  You can have partially-overlapping correct answers -- question A with correct answers B, C, and Z and question Q with correct answers R, S, and Z, where B is incorrect for Q and R is incorrect for A.  Even more common is that Z isn't quite a correct answer to the second question, but it is close enough to gain some upvotes.  In that case you really don't want those upvotes to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: The "very specific" in "*Questions on Stack Overflow are generally very specific.*" sounds a bit vague to me, and usually means "Low Quality" in "my" Tag ([imacros] - Web-Automation) where "*It is unlikely that an off-site resource answers the exact question posed on Stack Overflow.*" reads exactly *the other way around* as "It is unlikely that the answer provided on SO (fully!) answers the exact question posed on SO while the off-site link will provide much more info and will fully answer the question." // But "my" (small) Tag is a "Niche-Tag" and I further fully support this Proposal...

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, and for some concrete examples, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q

Answer (score 21):

I propose the following modified version (with special thanks to Henry Ecker for a long back-and-forth discussion, with many suggestions on improving this phrasing):

> Answers on Stack Overflow must be [self-contained](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Link-only answers can become useless if the linked page changes. Please [edit] your answer so that it contains a solution in the answer itself. Make sure to add your own explanation, provide [a link to the source of any copied content](/help/referencing), and be sure that it is [clear which parts of the answer are copied](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

This:

- Addresses [the point Wai Ha Lee raised in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420901/is-the-low-quality-answers-queue-review-comment-for-link-only-answers-providing#comment930391_420901) that the comment should address the issue of ensuring that the link-only answer is not replaced with a quote-only answer instead.
- Summarizes the requirements for appropriate attribution without requiring the reader to click any links (though the links are still provided).
- Simplifies the language used slightly.

Comment: I don't think we need the "If you use content that you did not create" portion of the conditional. It will always be true in any case where this comment is posted, since the comment is only posted when they're linking to something. Unless you're trying to draw the distinction for the edge case where someone posts a link-only answer linking to their own content? But then that's a different problem (undisclosed self-promotion), not an attribution issue.

Comment: @CodyGray Sometimes people replace the link with a summary they wrote themselves.  But...you're right, it actually reads entirely fine without that phrase, with no real loss in meaning.  I'll remove it.

Comment: Link-only answers become useless if the linked page changes and/or is removed. Therefore, answers on Stack Overflow must be [self-contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Please [edit] your answer to provide the solution in the text of the answer itself. Use [blockquote formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) to indicate anything you copy directly. Rewriting it in your own words is even better, if possible. Either way, make sure to [retain the link as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).